# In my edit file the information is not displaying in the text field rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails and in my project, the information in my total field is not displaying correctly. I know it's a problem with my syntax but I honestly can't figure out what is wrong. The number is displaying outside of the field. Can anybody offer some insight? This is happening with my "total" field.

```
  <% @cost.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <% end %>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :mini_description %><br>
<%= f.text_field :mini_description %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :description %><br>
<%= f.text_field :description %>
</div>
  `<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :quantity %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :quantity %>
  </div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :rate %><br>
<%= f.text_field :rate %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :total %><br>
<%= f.text_field :total %><%= @cost.cost_var %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :total_of_all_rows %><br/>
<%= f.text_field :total_of_all_rows %>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="actions">
 <%= f.submit %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

`

Comment: Can you make the example any shorter?  Also, which field has the problem?  When you say "my edit field", which field is that?

Comment: @JaredBeck it's my edit file that has the problem and this particular area: the total field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the value of the `:total` text field, use like this:

```
<%= f.text_field :total, :value => @cost.cost_var %>
```